# parar as a transitive verb

Tags: verbos

For the definition of [parar](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/parar) on SpanishDict, the following example is listed under transitive verb:

3. (to avoid)
   a. to block

Es tan importante parar como golpear. (Blocking is as important as punching.)

I'm having a hard time understanding why this is an example of usage as a transitive verb. I can't identify a direct object as I was under the impression that a verb could not be a direct object.

And, why would the sentence not be "Parar es tan importante como golpear."?

In either case es/is seems to be the verb to me. Whatever the verb is, I'm still curious whether the sentence is an example of a transitive or intransitive verb.

Comment: It is a mistake. In "Parar es tan importante como golpear," "parar" is intransitive.

Comment: That sentence in Spanish has no context. Just because there is no direct object does not mean it is not transitive. Please look up usages in the Real Academia: rae.es

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. You need at least a pronominal object for the verb to be transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence

> Parar es tan importante como golpear

"parar" is an infinitive form. Infinitives are non-conjugated forms, we could say (to understand) that they are not really verbs, but nouns.

If you want to understand "parar" as a transitive verb, you have to use it conjugated as the main verb of a sentence. For example

> El jugador paró la pelota con la mano.

Here, the blocked (the direct object) is "la pelota" (the ball).

Comment: You do not need to conjugate it: Parar la pelota es tan importante como hacer no-sé-que.